# PHP: remove MySQL formatting such as line break and commas

Tags: php, mysql, regex, csv

I'm making a CSV file, one of the database filed has stored a section called comments/note which obviously have some commas and line breaks in it too. Looked around the web found usage of preg_replace(), not much familiar with regular expressions there fore combined two different ones and not getting anything in result its totally blank and i know all records have some sort of comments in it

this i used

```
preg_replace( "/\r|\n/|/[,]/", "", $string )
```

Please what do I need to do here get one text back without line breaks and commas

Regards

Comment: Could you provide an example how the string looks?

Comment: Turn on error reporting. It'll be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using [strip_tags()](http://php.net/strip_tags) and [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace);

```
$clean_str = trim(preg_replace('/\s\s+/', '', strip_tags($string)));
```

or try this

```
$clean_str = str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n", ","), '', strip_tags($string));
```

Comment: no it did not worked only printing a integer value i.e 134 22 etc

Comment: share a sample string, it will be helpful

Comment: by the way comma still not removed from string... :(

Comment: Try second option, otherwise just run str_replace(', ', ' ',  $string)  on final string to get rid of commas